# A Sticky Situation In Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, collision-detection, game-physics, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to write a collision detection, but I'm getting some weird sticking behaviour, when I run into the object, it goes through, then when I go back, it sticks. what is going on here? the

module setup

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
```

setting up the variables

```
groundheight = 700
playersize = 50
PVx = 5
PVy = 0
playermass = 25
groundmass = 1000
playerx = 0
playery = -5
isgrounded = False
enemysize = 25
```

the player behavior

```
def forever():
    global PVx
    global PVy
    global playerx
    global playery
    global isgrounded
    enemyarray = canv.find_withtag("enemy")
    playerx = canv.coords("player")[2]-playersize/2
    playery = canv.coords("player")[3]-playersize/2
    canv.move("player", PVx, PVy)
    distoground = math.sqrt(math.pow(playery - groundheight, 2))
    if distoground <= playersize:
        PVy = 0
    else:
        isgrounded = False
        PVy += 0.1
    root.after(16, forever)
```

the enemy behavior

```
def enemyupdate():
    global PVx
    global PVy
    enemyarray = canv.find_withtag("enemy")
    for i in enemyarray:
        enemymass = 25
        Evx = 0
        EVy = 0
        x = canv.coords("enemy")[2]-playersize
        y = canv.coords("enemy")[3]-playersize
        distoground = math.sqrt(math.pow(y - groundheight, 2))
        distoplayer = math.sqrt(((x-playerx)**2)+((y-playery)**2))
        if distoground <= playersize:
            EVy = 0
        else:
            EVy += 5
```

**here's where the collisions happen**

```
        if distoplayer <= playersize+enemysize:
            tempx = Evx
            Evx = (playermass*PVx + enemymass*Evx)/(playermass+enemymass)
            PVx = (playermass*PVx + enemymass*Evx)/(playermass+enemymass)
```

```
        canv.move(i, Evx, EVy)
    root.after(16, enemyupdate)
```

receiving input

```
def getaxis(X):
    global PVx
    PVx = X
```

jump code for later

```
def jump(event):
    global PVy
    if isgrounded:
        PVy -= 5
```

tkinter main loop

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1920x1080")
root.state("zoomed")
canv = tk.Canvas(width=1920, height=1080, bg='light blue')
canv.create_rectangle(0, groundheight, 1920, 1080, fill="White")
player = canv.create_oval(0, 700, playersize, 700-playersize, fill="Red", tag="player")
canv.pack()
root.after(1, forever)
root.after(1, enemyupdate)
root.bind("<space>", jump)
root.bind("<Left>", lambda *args: getaxis(-5))
root.bind("<Right>", lambda  *args: getaxis(5))
for i in range(1):
    enemx = 500
    player = canv.create_oval(enemx+enemysize, 700, enemx - enemysize, 700-enemysize*2, fill="Red", tag="enemy")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you examined the values going into the calculations, and examined the values after the calculations to see if they are what you think they should be?

Comment: I've tried to change the distance that it collides. doesn't work

Comment: That doesn't actually answer my question. Have you sat down with pencil and paper to compute what the values of the variables should be before and after a collision, and then compared them to what is actually being calculated?

Comment: no. i'm too dumb to do that.